# Does the number of columns in editionable view affect performance

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, if I have a table with 50 columns, is there any performance difference between a view which references 4 columns versus a view which references all.

For example -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW V_VIEW1 AS select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1;
```

versus

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW V_VIEW1 AS select * from table1;
```

Is there any difference between these? I tried googling but the keyword view is being interpreted as action view.

Comment: Some more data to move around. May or may not make any difference.

Comment: what if there are 300 columns? may or may not cracked me up, lol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you use the view.  If you run:

```
select * from v_view1;
```

then clearly the second view is returning more data, so should take a bit longer (maybe not much longer).

But if you run:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from v_view1;
```

then there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to verify this? I mean, can I find this in the oracle documentation?

Comment: I couldn't point you to it if there is.  You just have to understand what a view is - it is a stored query, not a table.  If you only select 3 columns from a 50 column view, Oracle doesn't have to fetch the 47 columns you don't want.  The optimizer figures out what you want, and gets it.

Comment: What difference does it make. If the require is for for the 50 columns, you cannot use the view with 4. If the requirement is 4 columns then you cannot use the one for 50.